# How to store label value in core_config_data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, core-config-data

I want to store label value in core_config_data. Mostly the input values are store. If there is no row then the magento creates it. 
But why the label value is not created.

```
<field id="last_sync" translate="label comment" type="label" sortOrder="9" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Last Sync on </label>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in your code: **"type='text' "**

```
<field id="last_sync" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="9" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
  <label>Last Sync on </label>
```

Comment: The thing is i don't want text there

Comment: can you share a file?